# Is it possible to change the certificate for a Safari Extension with auto update?

Tags: safari-extension

Would it be possible to change the Safari Developer certificate (created with a different email) of an extension and still have it auto update to all users?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to get a new certificate, as you won't be able to change any info on a digital certificate.

Comment: Do you know if auto update would still work? That's what I'm worried about.

Comment: it probably should. I haven't experienced it though. sorry